# whats the difference between Optional.ofNullable vs Optional.fromNullable

Tags: java

I am working on a java app, and I found this two options:

one is native from jdk Optional.ofNullable and other Optional.fromNullable from the guava library.

On simple term, do they mean the same? using fromNullable with non java8 apps is the equivalente of ofNullabe?

reading the doc I found:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

```
A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.
Additional methods that depend on the presence or absence of a contained value are provided, such as orElse() (return a default value if value not present) and ifPresent() (execute a block of code if the value is present).

This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations (including reference equality (==), identity hash code, or synchronization) on instances of Optional may have unpredictable results and should be avoided.
```

vs

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html

```
An immutable object that may contain a non-null reference to another object. Each instance of this type either contains a non-null reference, or contains nothing (in which case we say that the reference is "absent"); it is never said to "contain null".
A non-null Optional<T> reference can be used as a replacement for a nullable T reference. It allows you to represent "a T that must be present" and a "a T that might be absent" as two distinct types in your program, which can aid clarity.

Some uses of this class include

As a method return type, as an alternative to returning null to indicate that no value was available
To distinguish between "unknown" (for example, not present in a map) and "known to have no value" (present in the map, with value Optional.absent())
To wrap nullable references for storage in a collection that does not support null (though there are several other approaches to this that should be considered first)
A common alternative to using this class is to find or create a suitable null object for the type in question.

This class is not intended as a direct analogue of any existing "option" or "maybe" construct from other programming environments, though it may bear some similarities.

Comparison to java.util.Optional (JDK 8 and higher): A new Optional class was added for Java 8. The two classes are extremely similar, but incompatible (they cannot share a common supertype). All known differences are listed either here or with the relevant methods below.
```

Any idea if both can be taken as "same" when talking about nulls handling?

Comment: Wow, you're asking a question, and you then pasted in javadoc that guides you to the answer. Perhaps you should ***read the javadoc*** you're pasting into the question!!!!!! Last line of pasted javadoc starts *"Comparison to `java.util.Optional` ..."* **The javadoc has already done the comparison you're asking for.** *<sheesh>*

Comment: I did read it, as I mentioned, was not clear for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea if both can be taken as "same" when talking about nulls
>   handling?

Yes, they're equivalent as the documentation states:

[fromNullable](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#fromNullable(T))

```
public static <T> Optional<T> fromNullable(@Nullable
                           T nullableReference)
```

> If nullableReference is non-null, returns an Optional instance
>   containing that reference; otherwise returns absent(). **Comparison to
>   java.util.Optional: this method is equivalent to Java 8's
>   Optional.ofNullable.**

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the guava docs:

**Comparison to java.util.Optional (JDK 8 and higher):**

A new Optional class was added for Java 8. The two classes are extremely similar, but incompatible (they cannot share a common supertype). All known differences are listed either here or with the relevant methods below.

- This class is serializable; java.util.Optional is not.
- java.util.Optional has the additional methods ifPresent, filter, flatMap, and orElseThrow.
- java.util offers the primitive-specialized versions OptionalInt, OptionalLong and OptionalDouble, the use of which is recommended; Guava does not have these.

There are no plans to deprecate this class in the foreseeable future. However, we do gently recommend that you prefer the new, standard Java class whenever possible.

See the Guava User Guide article on using Optional.

In other words, these methods are equivalent, class and instances are not.